# How do I add curlpp to my project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, curlpp

I'm trying to make a transition from vb.net to C++ and I'm stuck on this. I downloaded curlpp from [here](http://code.google.com/p/curlpp/downloads/detail?name=curlppMD.zip&can=2&q=) which got me a .dll, .exp and .lib file. I added the directory that contains those 3 files to "Additional Library Directories" in the project properties (Linker -> General).

Next, I added ws2_32.lib and Wldap32.lib to "Additional Dependencies", also in the project properties (Linker -> Input) because [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306045/installing-libcurl-on-visual-studio-2010) stated I should.

Now I'm trying to get [Example 00](http://curlpp.org/index.php/examples/47-example-00) to work, but

```
#include <curlpp/curlpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>
```

States "cannot open source file curlpp/curlpp.hpp" etc. which makes sense because I have never even seen those files. What am I doing wrong? This is quite different from vb.net and I can't seem to figure it out.

UPDATE:

I did what Mat said, but it didn't work, so I added all relevent folders to be sure.
[image: includes]

But VS still states the files can't be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should download the full source package (`.tar.gz` in the [downloads](http://code.google.com/p/curlpp/downloads/list) section) to get the headers, code, samples and documentation.

You'll need to add the base directory where the include files reside on your machine (after unpacking the archive) to the list of include directories for your project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mat, unfortunately VS still states the files can't be found. I updated my question to clarify what I tried.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same message **exactly**? (The only path you need is `.../curlpp-0.7.3/include`.)

Comment: In addition to the message I was already getting, another error seems to have popped up: "Cannot open include file: 'curlpp/cURLpp.hpp': No such file or directory"

Comment: Figured it out. I was adding the directory to (Linker -> General) which is for libraries, when I should have been adding it to (C/C++ -> General) which is for includes.. d'oh! Thanks for the help.